# Find the equation whose graph is symmetric about the y-axis and has local maxima at $(−3,2)$ and $(3,2)$ and a y-intercept of $-1$.

Tags: derivatives

I have been trying to get this for the last 3 hours. Please someone help me.

Find the equation of a quartic polynomial whose graph is symmetric about the y-axis and has local maxima at $(−3,2)$ and $(3,2)$ and a y-intercept of $-1$.

Comment: Hint: Since your polynomial $y = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2+dx+e\;$  is symmetric about the y-axis it has only even powers of $x$. This gives you two coefficients. From value at $x=0\;$ you find e. And for the remaining two coefficients you have two pairs (x,y): The values of $y(x)$ and $y'(x)$ at one maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this not tagged homework, I expand my comment to an answer.

With $y(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e,\;$ the symmetry and $y(0) = 1\,$ we have
$y(x) = ax^4+cx^2+1$ and $y'(x) = 4ax^3+2cx$. The coordinates of the maximum  $y(3)=2$ give $81a + 9c + 1 = 2.\;$ 
The zero of the first derivative at $x=3$ supplies the last equation
$108a + 6c =0 \iff 18a +c =0 \iff c=-18a$. Substituting this $c$ in the maximum equation shows $a=-1/81$, and finally $c=2/9$. So resulting equation is 
$$y(x) = -\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^4 + 2\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)^2 + 1$$
 [image: Sketch of polynomial]